# Select preceding/following-sibling XPath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am using Selenium with Python and I wanna select the html before hr tag.
Here's the code I have:

```
<div id="wikipage">
<div id="wikipage-inner">
<h1>Berkeley</h1>
<p><span><strong>Title1</strong></span></p>
<p><strong>Address: </strong>..</p>
<p><strong>Website: </strong><a href="..">..</a></p>
<p><strong>Phone: </strong>..</p>

<hr />

<p><strong><span">Title2</span></strong></p>
<p><strong>Address: </strong>..</p>
<p><strong>Website:</strong> <a href="..">..</a></p>
<p><strong>Phone:</strong> ..</p>
<p><strong>Email:</strong> <a href="mailto:..">..</a></p>

<hr />
</div>
</div>
```

I am using regex to extract title-address-website-phone-email .. into a csv file, so I need the text before each hr tag in the whole web page.
The result will be a list, something like this

```
This is a text before hr: Title1 Adress: .. Website: .. Phone: ..
This is a text before hr: Title2 Adress ..
```

when writing:

```
for p in parag:
    print('This is a text before hr: ', p.text)
```

I will appreciate some help guys.

Comment: What HTML element do you want to select??? Could you explain more. do you want all `<p>` before `<hr>`???

Comment: ...and there are two `hr` elements.  Which one?

Comment: What XPath expressions have you tried? What was the result, and what was the exact result you wanted?

Comment: @LarsH I am not very comfortable with Xpath nor with following-sibling, It did great job for me before and now I thought of preceding-sibling, I don't know if there's a way to achieve what i want here .. Didn't try much ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### If you have fixed numbers of `<p>` nodes you can try this xpath:

```
//hr[x]/preceding-sibling::p[position()<=y]
```

Where **x** is position of your `<hr/>` tag and **y** is number of `<p>` tags before `<hr/>`

So for example if i want to select all 5 `<p>` nodes before second `<hr/>` i will use this xpath:

```
//hr[2]/preceding-sibling::p[position()<=5]
```

#### If you dont have fixed number of `<p>` tags you have to use more complicated xpath:

```
//hr[x]/preceding-sibling::p[position()<=count(//hr[x]/preceding-sibling::p) - count(//hr[y]/preceding-sibling::p)]
```

Where **x** is position  of the bottom `<hr/>` tag and **y** is position of top `<hr/>` tag.

So to select the same nodes like i selected in first example you have to use this xpath:

```
//hr[2]/preceding-sibling::p[position()<=count(//hr[2]/preceding-sibling::p) - count(//hr[1]/preceding-sibling::p)]
```

With this i selected all `<p>` tags between first `<hr/>` and second `<hr/>`

Comment: Thank you, it worked as supposed, I don't have an hr tag at the top and the bottom, maybe I can go with this solution. It's the best I have.

Comment: Maybe I can use BeautifulSoup?